# Merge 'sync' and 'synchronization'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) × 14

[synchronization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) × 2

One question actually has both tags.

I think "sync" is used more because, well, it's a simple abbreviation and the full word is hard to spell. Also, a lot of devices have used "Sync" as their official term for what they're doing with your data. (I know that all those years I used a Palm device I don't know that I ever saw the word "synchronization" in any documentation.)

The grammarian in me prefers spelling the word out, but I'll go with the community's preference.

Comment: I think I'm the only person left in the world who spells it "synch" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed.  Plus there is the synchronization vs synchronisation depending on English locale.

I moved synchronization and synchronisation to sync.  Vote on synonym here: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/sync/synonyms

Comment: Thanks. Not enough rep to vote, though.

Comment: whiner. there are at least (and at most) TWO USERS who have enough rep to vote!

Comment: Ok, I voted.  So were pretty much stuck with the tags as they stand until there's 4 people over 1000?

Comment: More or less, yes.  We can re-tag things manually for the moment.  I'm not sure if full-power mods can set these up without votes or not, either